# how to add button in vertical in jtoolbar and maintain gap between buttons?

Tags: java

*i don't know how to add button in jtoolbar,whenever i introduce JToolBar 
  onetoolbar = new JToolBar(JToolBar.VERTICAL),it shows buttons without toolbar
  in irregular manner
  *second one is as i've tried a lot toolbar_name.addseparator() is not working at all which is used to maintain gap b/w buttons in jtoolbar so plz help me to get rid of it!

```
  import java.awt.*;
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.sql.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  import javax.swing.JToolBar;
  import java.awt.Container;



    public class paint implements ActionListener
    {

    JFrame oneframe;
    JPanel onepanel,twopanel,threepanel,fourpanel,fivepanel,sixpanel;
    JTabbedPane onepane;

    Font onefont,twofont;
    JButton fileButton,viewButton,homeButton,newButton,openButton;
    JButton saveButton,printButton,exitButton;
    JButton redButton,yellowButton,greenButton;
    JButton ovalButton,rectangleButton,circleButton;
    JButton cutButton,copyButton,pasteButton;
    JTable dataTable,staffTable,onedataTable,onestaffTable,complaintTable;



    int colorcheck,tollcheck,x,y,x1,y1;
    BorderLayout bl;
    public paint() 
    {

    oneframe=new JFrame("Paint");
    onepanel=new JPanel();
    twopanel=new JPanel();
    //twopanel=(JPanel)getContentPane();
    threepanel=new JPanel();
    fourpanel=new JPanel();
    fivepanel=new JPanel();
    sixpanel=new JPanel();

    onepanel.setLayout(null);




    fileButton=new JButton("File");
    homeButton=new JButton("Home");
    viewButton=new JButton("View");
    newButton=new JButton("New");
    openButton=new JButton("Open");
    saveButton=new JButton("Save");
    printButton=new JButton("Print");
    exitButton=new JButton("Exit");

    JToolBar onetoolbar = new JToolBar();
    onetoolbar.add(newButton);
    onetoolbar.add(openButton);
    onetoolbar.add(saveButton);
    onetoolbar.add(printButton);
    onetoolbar.add(exitButton);
    //toolbar.setRollover(true);
    //onetoolbar.setMargin(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    onetoolbar.setFloatable(false);
   onetoolbar.addSeparator();
    onetoolbar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500,30));

    onetoolbar.setBounds(0,0,1500,30);
    //twopanel.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.WEST);
    onepanel.add(onetoolbar);
    oneframe.add(onepanel);
    //twopanel.setLayout(null);
    //bl=new BorderLayout();
    twopanel.setLayout(null);
    cutButton=new JButton("Cut");
    //cutButton.setBounds(5,5,70,25);
    copyButton=new JButton("Copy");
    //copyButton.setBounds(80,5,70,25);
    pasteButton=new JButton("Paste");
    //pasteButton.setBounds(40,35,70,25);


    JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar(JToolBar.VERTICAL);
    toolbar.add(cutButton);
    toolbar.add(copyButton);
    toolbar.add(pasteButton);
    //toolbar.setRollover(true);
    toolbar.setFloatable(false);

    toolbar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));
    toolbar.setBounds(0,0,200,400);
    //twopanel.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.WEST);
    twopanel.add(toolbar);
    oneframe.add(twopanel);







    Font font=new Font("PLAYBILL",Font.BOLD,32);
    //headingLabel.setFont(font);
    //headingLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    onepane=new JTabbedPane();
    onepane.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    Font tfont=new Font("Cntury Gothic",Font.BOLD,15);
    onepane.setFont(tfont);

    newButton.addActionListener(this);
    openButton.addActionListener(this);
    saveButton.addActionListener(this);
    printButton.addActionListener(this);
    exitButton.addActionListener(this);




      onepane.addTab("File",onepanel);  //adding buttons in tab
        onepane.addTab("Home", twopanel);
        onepane.addTab("View",threepanel);
        oneframe.add(onepane);
        oneframe.setSize(1500,1500);
       // oneframe.setResizable(false);
        oneframe.setVisible(true);

     }


      public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
     new paint();
     }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
   {
    if(evt.getSource().equals(newButton))
    {
         JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(paint.this.oneframe,  
                    "Do you want to Save?");
    }


    else if(evt.getSource().equals(openButton))
    {
        JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
        int result=chooser.showOpenDialog(oneframe);
        if(result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
             System.out.println("File Opened");
        }
    }


    else if(evt.getSource().equals(saveButton))
        {
            JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
            int result=chooser.showSaveDialog(oneframe);
            if(result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                 System.out.println("File Saved");
            }
            }

    /*else if(evt.getSource().equals(printButton))
    {
        /*JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
        int result=chooser.showSaveDialog(oneframe);

    }    */
    else if(evt.getSource().equals(printButton))
    {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(paint.this.oneframe, "Do you want to print?");

    }
    else if(evt.getSource().equals(exitButton))
    {
        int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION;
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Do you want to save Existing data?","Do you want to save?",dialogButton);
        {
            if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
                int result=chooser.showSaveDialog(oneframe);
                if(result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                {
                     System.out.println("File Saved");
                }
                }
            else
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }




    }

        }



        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the code changes below. The parameters for `setBounds()` method had to be modified to correctly display the buttons vertically. Also `addSeparator()` method is not working and hence a workaround to add a separator after each button has been suggested below.

```
    JToolBar onetoolbar = new JToolBar(JToolBar.VERTICAL);
    onetoolbar.add(newButton);
    onetoolbar.add(new JSeparator());
    onetoolbar.add(openButton);
    onetoolbar.add(new JSeparator());
    onetoolbar.add(saveButton);
    onetoolbar.add(new JSeparator());
    onetoolbar.add(printButton);
    onetoolbar.add(new JSeparator());
    onetoolbar.add(exitButton);
    onetoolbar.setFloatable(false);
    onetoolbar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500, 30));
    onetoolbar.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 200);
```

I would suggest to go for a `JMenuBar` instead of `JToolBar` to give a nice look and feel to the application.

Comment: thanks for your valuable time buddy but i want to use jtoolbar and tabs

Comment: In case the suggested code changes have worked for you, please accept the answer.